# VueJs3 Data Object is not being updated via Watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

M1y aim is to fill this empty reactive data property with an object from my store.

```
let matchedFile = reactive({});
```

I return an object from my store below

```
const matchedFiles = computed(() => {
  return store.activeFile;
});
```

I watch the above computed

```
watch(matchedFiles, async (newVal) => {
  updateMatchedF(newVal);
});
```

Which in turn calls the following method:

```
function updateMatchedF(val) {
      matchedFile = val;
    }

Object being passed (proxy)

    {
    "name": "Hello World",
    "id": 12311,
    "title": "test file"
    }
```

For some reason, the object is succesfully passed to the very last method, and console.log even shows a succesful update. But VueTools shows an empty object.
What am I not doing right here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way how a variable can be reactive when it's reassigned like `matchedFile = val`. In this case it should be a ref and change a reference at some point.

Also if there's a chance that watched value is available at the time when the component is instantiated, the watcher should be immediate.

It's preferable to use `null` instead of empty object to distinguish empty value:

```
const matchedFile = ref(null);

watch(matchedFiles, async (newVal) => {
  updateMatchedF(newVal);
}, { immediate: true });

function updateMatchedF(val) {
  matchedFile.value = val;
}
```